# Pick column with default value or column with user defined value if not null?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, schema

I'm working on a webapp with a set of data that users can browse and edit.

Users want to customize one of the fields that appear for each item, say "product_name".

Each product has a set of default values in a table, which is the same for all users:

The product table would be like (skipping syntax cruft, you get the idea):

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  pid     int,            # product id
  pname   varchar         # product name (users want to customize this)
);
```

I need to display the user's customized product name in all tables/lists on my site whenever there is a customized value for that product, but otherwise display the default value.

For space efficiency I thought of using an extra table that sort of "overrides" the default values, for any given user, for any given product. The rows are added in this table as needed. A user that did not customize any product name would not have any rows in there:

```
CREATE TABLE custom (
  pid     int,
  userid  int,
  pname   varchar
);
```

I can easily join these two tables on product id, and could pick the default (products.pname) , or user-edited value (custom.pname) for each row in php, but I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to do this in MySQL.

Is there an expression that lets me pick one column if not null otherwise pick another (accross two tables) ?

Would you suggest a different way to handle this ?

Thank you.

PS: maybe a type of JOIN that would allow a column of table 2 with the same name to override a column in table 1 for those rows where it exists in table 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the COALESCE function.

```
SELECT COALESCE(the_field, "This literal") FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

results in the_field if the_field is not null, otherwise it is "This literal". You can mix fields and literals as much as you want .. so SELECT COALESCE(this_field, that_field) works too. You can have more than 2 parameters ... e.g. SELECT COALESCE(this_field,that_field, theother_field)

Comment: Thanks. I found a similar operator called IFNULL(). IFNULL(expr1, expr2) appears to be equivalent to COALESCE(expr1, expr2). I'm not sure what use there is to this variant since COALESCE() can take more than two arguments.

Comment: @faB: IFNULL is MySQL specific; `COALESCE` is ANSI standard, and can be used on various databases.  As you mentioned, `COALESCE` also can take more than two parameters.  Most recommend using ANSI syntax whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of LEFT JOIN and COALESCE:

```
   SELECT p.pid,
          COALESCE(c.pname, p.pname) AS product_name
     FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN CUSTOM c ON c.pid = p.pid
                  AND c.userid = ?
```

Because `c.pname` will be null if the user hasn't provided a custom name, the `COALESCE` function will default to using the next non-NULL value--from `p.pname`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select if(c.pname is not null, c.pname, p.pname) pname
  from products p left outer join custom c on c.pid = p.pid;
```

The left outer join always delivers a row match, which will have null fields if the join fails, you can test that with the if() function.

Comment: Ah, I thought there must be something like a ternary operator.  It will be interesting to research this and coalesce now in the ref manual and see how approaches differ. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MySQL's [`CASE`-statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html). This should do the trick:

```
   SELECT CASE
              WHEN `custom`.`pname` IS NULL
              THEN `products`.`pname`
              ELSE `custom`.`pname`
          END CASE AS `pname`
     FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `custom`
       ON `custom`.`pid` = `products`.`pid`
    WHERE `products`.`pid` = 123
```

I did not test this, but this is how it should work basically.

Comment: Thanks, anyway to do this with a plain SELECT query? I haven't used any "stored program" (stored procedure?) on this app yet, and don't have a framework for it yet.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting CASE in a SELECT statement.